# Access non object in observableArray

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

Refer to this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/SimonYong/NasR6/). 
I got an array named Header (store name for table header) and another array named Type (store class name for each column). I wonder how to get access to the Type array using Header index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that in a binding expression like that you need to call $index with brackets, i.e.:

```
$root.Type()[$index()]
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KuzGf/1/

Comment: No worries. The reason you need the brackets here is because the value of $index itself forms part of the binding expression which determines the value for "class". If you were binding to $index in isolation (e.g. to just render the index in a span) you wouldn't need it.